# Bootstrap form merge rows

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I need create a form using input type like the image in attachment, my question is how I merge rows to look like this picture[image]

can help me and explain how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need some nested row and col div's.  A basic example I mocked up in Bootply.  Also attaching code for reference.

The gist of this is, you have 12 columns to work with.  If your first column is 12 and then your second is 8 | 4, then your 8 column can have 12 more inside of it.  That can happen infinitely, technically, but eventually, you'll not be able to have anything legible :)

```
<!-- main outer row -->
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
main row
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-8">
    Left
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-1">
        1 col
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        3 col
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2">
        2 col
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2">
        3 col
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        4 col
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        3 col
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2">
        2 col
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1">
        1 col
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        4 col
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2">
        2 col
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        12 col
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        6 col
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        6 col
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    Right
    <br><br>
      all the data
      <br>
      all the data
      <br>
      all the data
      <br>
      all the data
      <br>all the data
      <br>
      all the data
      <br>


  </div>
</div>
```

http://www.bootply.com/o2Rnuh4gqQ